# Website Development: What are these files "name pclzip-xxxxxxxx.tmp" in public_html folder of a website?

Tags: wordpress

I found some files with names in this manner under the "public_html" folder of my website? Are these files important or we can delete them?
"pclzip-630fac779f733.tmp" and 20+ more files. I have attached screenshot for your reference.
[public_html directory view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jgi1n.jpg)

I tried finding information on these files but didn't got any solution anywhere. So I need help of a professional WordPress web developer in identifying these files.

Comment: These are probably files of a backup plugin

Comment: Looks like something within your site is probably using the PclZip library to generate ZIP files. Since they all have `.tmp` as suffix, it is probably safe to delete them. Whether they should have been generated there, instead of the existing `tmp` dir, is perhaps a different question.

Comment: They are temporary files. Temporary files are often created by applications or processes to store temporary data.

Comment: Thank you for this information. I have deleted the files from cPanel to clean up the website disk storage. Thanks a lot guys.